# Copy a directory when logged in via ssh to my desktop via terminal

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

How can I copy a directory to my local desktop from a remote machine ? I accessing the remote machine via ssh in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways...

**Using `scp`**

On your Mac, in Terminal, make a directory on your Desktop to store the remote files:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/remote
```

Then use `scp` to copy some files from the remote host to your Mac:

```
scp remoteHost:path/to/directory/*  ~/Desktop/remote
```

**Using `rsync`**

Make a directory on your Desktop into which to copy the remote files:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/remote
```

Now use `rsync` to make a synchronised copy of a directory on the remote machine in that folder on your Mac:

```
rsync -av RemoteMachine:path/to/directory/* ~/Desktop/remote
```

**Using `tar` and `ssh`**

In the Terminal on your Mac, run this:

```
ssh remoteMachine "tar -cf - /path/to/SomeDirectory" > ~/Desktop/RemoteDir.tar
```

That will log into the remote machine and create a tar file of the specified directory and write it to `stdout`. That will be picked up on your Mac and redirected into tar file on your Mac's Desktop that you can inspect with the Archiver or similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easier way, install a FTP CLient like FileZilla. https://filezilla-project.org/download.php.